# CC for python distutils to build c

Tags: python, c, linux

I was trying to build c through python distutils. I want to replace CC with gcc and follow this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737260/how-to-tell-distutils-to-use-gcc)

```
CC=gcc python setup.py build
```

Then I got

> **gcc** -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c hello.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/hello.o
>
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
>
> **x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc** -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/hello.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/hello.so

CC only changed to gcc on first stage, and it would become original x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc, I am not sure is there anything missing, thanks.

Comment: How about defining the linker with LD?

Comment: didn't work, However, I found the answer, it was LDSHARED needed to be defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986256/python-distutils-gcc-path), LDSHARED is the variable I need.

The full command would be like this

```
CC=gcc LDSHARED=gcc -pthread -shared python setup.py build
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set "CC" with

`os.environ["CC"] = "GCC"`

However, this sometimes does not work in windows and involves some changes in the config files.

1. Create file "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg" and write this inside

Then insert the following code:

`[build]
 compiler = gcc`

2. Remove all instances of "-mno-cygwin" gcc option from file "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py":
3. In the same file convert this:

   `self.set_executables(compiler='gcc -mno-cygwin -O -Wall',
                             compiler_so='gcc -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall',
                             compiler_cxx='g++ -mno-cygwin -O -Wall',
                             linker_exe='gcc -mno-cygwin',
                             linker_so='%s -mno-cygwin %s %s'
                                 % (self.linker_dll, shared_option,
                                     entry_point))`

   to this:

   `self.set_executables(compiler='gcc -O -Wall',
                            compiler_so='gcc -mdll -O -Wall',
                            compiler_cxx='g++ -O -Wall',
                            linker_exe='gcc',
                            linker_so='%s %s %s'
                                % (self.linker_dll, shared_option,
                                    entry_point))`